# What's the perception DC of a shout spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, skills, house-rules

In the spell [Shout](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shout), I can make an extremely loud scream

> You emit an ear-splitting yell that deafens and damages creatures in its path.

I don't think there's any rules at all for especially loud and magical effects, but what would be considered a fair distance before the perception DC is above 0 in normal conditions? I'm asking as factors like several doors and hallways in a dungeon can limit the distance of a shout, along with forests, and sometimes there's a sleeping dragon or powerful monster nearby that could wake up from this otherwise powerful spell.

On a slightly related note, would it be allowed to yell a specific phrase or word, rather than just a random yell, even though the range is 30 ft. I'm sure that the listed range is simply the deafening effect, not the actual range of hearing the shout (Your ally can stand behind you, and not hear a thing, as it's a cone shaped burst), so not all listeners will be deafened.

Comment: You might want to consider asking the second half of this, about specific words/phrases as a separate question. As can be seen from the first answer you have, it is likely to get missed by people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no hard rules for Perception, there are so many possibilities in terms of what characters might hear, see, or smell in a given situation that they just gave a reference table. The item on the table that likely most fits with this situation is "Hear the sound of battle - DC –10" though a final ruling is up to your DM.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with MrTumnus that -10 is a good baseline, although +10 for sleeping applies as well, for +0 base. Then you apply distance modifiers as usual, of course. For a sleeping dragon, say a young adult black dragon, that works out to having an even chance of waking up (rolling 11 or higher) if *shout* goes off 320 feet away, not counting closed doors intervening, each of which is as good as 50 feet.